# Grails doesn't start, stuck at postProcessBeanFactory

Tags: maven, grails, groovy

I'm working on my laptop (win10) and I can start my Grails app without any problems.
I'm trying to be able to also work from my desktop (win10) but Grails fails to launch my app.

I installed the same Java version (1.8) and same Grails version (2.5.1) and I used Git to clone the source code of my application.

I have no problem running the commands:

```
grails clean-all
grails refresh-dependencies
```

But when I do **grails run-app**, then it gets stuck:

```
| Dependencies refreshed.

| Compiling 10 source files

| Compiling 241 source files
Note: C:\Users\xxx\workspace\customer-portal\target\work\plugins\scaffolding-2.1.2\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\scaffolding\AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
| Compiling 32 source files

| Compiling 32 source files.....
2018-05-16/14:35:23.737 [main]  INFO  webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin - Loading default config file: class DefaultWebXmlConfig
2018-05-16/14:35:23.764 [main]  WARN  webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin - Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig
2018-05-16/14:35:24.472 [main]  INFO  webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin - Loading default config file: class DefaultWebXmlConfig
| Running Grails application
2018-05-16/14:35:29.298 [localhost-startStop-1]  INFO  [localhost].[/customer_portal] - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContextConfiguring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2018-05-16/14:35:39.015 [localhost-startStop-1]  INFO  cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor - postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry start
2018-05-16/14:35:39.028 [localhost-startStop-1]  INFO  cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor - postProcessBeanFactory
```

I waited more then 30min but nothing happened and CPU usage is 0%.

What could be wrong on my desktop that prevent Grails to start?

Comment: Follow this instructions to configure your logs at debug level in order to inspect what's happening

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/grails-goodness-set-log-level-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jorge-aguilera-gonzalez for the link. I set everything in **Config.groovy** to "debug".
I could see it was hanging while connecting to the DB. I had to allow the desktop IP to connect to the database (grant privileges)...

Now it is working!